# Where is the return address stored in x64 ms fastcall?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, calling-convention

Curious where the return address is stored in the x64 Microsoft Fastcall implementation. Cheers.

Comment: There is no x64 fastcall calling convention.  The normal cdecl calling convention uses registers to pass arguments.

Comment: On the stack as usual. It's still using `CALL` instruction.

Comment: I checked the esp + 0x8 and no return address. any tips?

Comment: It's at `rsp` (unless you did something with the stack).

Comment: It's giving a valid address, but not where the return should be. Is this a sign of something? Thanks!

Comment: We don't know what you are doing. The return address is on the top of the stack at `rsp` at function entry and also at the end at the `ret` for obvious reasons. Any change of`rsp` will of course change the offset.

Comment: The only thing I'm doing to the stack is moving something to r9. Is the return address by any chance relative or absolute? I don't know just curious.

Comment: @RossRidge: MS does call their standard x64 convention fastcall in their documentation, because it's derived from 32-bit fastcall (same first 2 args), although the x64 is caller-pops stack.  e.g. "The x64 ABI uses a four-register fast-call calling convention by default" in https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/x64-calling-convention?view=vs-2019.  And https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/x64-software-conventions?view=vs-2019 says "x64 uses the `__fastcall` calling convention".  (The other Windows x64 calling convention is `__vectorcall` which AFAIK differs only for wider SIMD args)

Comment: Post some code, please.  It's almost certain that the return address is exactly where it should be (and it's absolute, by the way) and that something is wrong with the way you're trying to inspect it.  But without seeing your code there is no way we can guess what is wrong.

Comment: BTW, I tested and `__fastcall` does override `-Gv`, giving you the old convention even when `__vectorcall` is the default.  https://godbolt.org/z/GFrwKM.  So fastcall is 100% a real name that MS uses, and has meaning in their compiler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Same as every other x86 / x86-64 calling convention, it's on the stack on function entry, pointed to by `rsp`.  Calls are still made using [`call`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/CALL.html), which pushes an 8-byte absolute return address and jumps to the target address.

So if you run a [`ret`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/ret) instruction while RSP has the value it did on entry, it will pop that return address back into RIP.  (`ret` is how we write `pop rip` on x86-64.)  This should be clear if you look at compiler generated code which either just uses `ret`, or if it moves RSP inside the function, restores it again before running a `ret`.

MS documents stack layout for their x64 calling convention.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/stack-usage?view=vs-2019.  Also docs for [x64 __fastcall](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/x64-calling-convention?view=vs-2019) in general.  (And yes, MS do call it x64 `__fastcall`, even though it and x64 `__vectorcall` are the only 2 calling conventions they support for x86-64.  x64 `__fastcall` is slightly similar to 32-bit `__fastcall`, but the x64 version is caller-pops the stack and with more registers for arg-passing.  And differences in xmm registers being call-preserved.  It does use the same first 2 integer registers, though, hence the name I guess.)

Whatever your problem is, it's probably not this.  Although you mentioned ESP in comments.  If you run `sub esp, 8` in 64-bit code, you'll truncate RSP to 32 bits, leading to a fault next time you try to push/pop or call.

Comment: SUPER helpful, for some reason it's still not working (my fault). 

mov    QWORD PTR [rsp+0x8],rbx
mov    QWORD PTR [rsp+0x10],rbp
mov    QWORD PTR [rsp+0x18],rsi
push   rdi
sub    rsp,0x60
mov    r9,QWORD PTR [rsp]

right here I am trying to pass the return address of the current function as a param in the r9 register to another function. It's giving an invalid address.

Comment: @Deud1eSkrub: you change RSP with `push` and `sub` so it's no longer pointing to the return address by the time you run `mov r9, [rsp]`.  Use a debugger to single-step your code and show a dump of memory above RSP after each instruction if you're having trouble picturing this in your head.